# How to convert WrappedArray[String ] to delimited String

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have xml schema of following structure

[image]

**I am interested in _EventStartDateand and E** these values have to be converted into an AVRO record at the end date being the key and E being the value.

**To convert this i use databricks XML parser and then create a temporary table and then repartition it on date.**

```
import org.apache.spark.{ SparkContext, SparkConf }
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import com.databricks.spark.avro._

val xmlDF = 
sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag", "Events").load("/hdfsPath").cache
xmlDF.registerTempTable("event_tbl")
val xmlDF_Tbl = sqlContext.sql("SELECT `@EventStartDate` as eventDate,E as event FROM event_tbl")
val xmlDF_Tbl_Part = xmlDF_Tbl.repartition($"eventDate").rdd.map(s => (s(0),s(1).toString))
xmlDF_Tbl_Part.saveAsTextFile("path to Hdfs")
```

**i get output in following format 2015,WrappedArray([E1], [E2])**

**i want output in following format 2015,E1@@@E2@@@E3 and so on**

The DF looks something like this:

**[@BL: string, @EventStartDate: string, @MaterialNumber: bigint, @SerialNumber: bigint, @UTCOfs: bigint, E:array[struct<@C:string,@EID:bigint,@Hst:string,@L:bigint,@MID:string,@S:string,@Src:string,@T:string,@Tgt:string,@Usr:string,@VALUE:string>]]**

Now how to convert this wrapped array to a delimited string

Comment: TL,DR; Have you tried `wrappedArrayObj.mkString("@@@")` ? like exactly `map(s => (s(0),s(1).mkString("@@@")))`

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do, in your desired string ("2015,E1@@@E2@@@E3") I'm assuming "2015" is the `_EventStartDate`. What are "E1", "E2" and "E3"? The `toString()` value of the `E` struct? Is it one of the properties on `E` specifically?

Comment: @JackLeow as you can infer from the schema that E(events) is an Array of Struct and hereby E1, E2... En i refer to individual Elements of the array. Each element is of type struct(in schema denoted as element). Now what i want to do is to club all the events (E) together for that date. technically the problem is to convert an Array of Struct to a List of Strings with custom delimiter

Comment: Also have added the DF in the question